# Having trouble installing buildslave on Windows 7

Tags: python, twisted, buildbot, zope.interface

I finally got `pip install buildbot-slave` to work on Win7 (thanks to another answer on this site), and now when I attempt to create a build slave via:

`buildslave create-slave slavefolder blah.blah.com:9989 buildslave password`

It kicks back the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\buildslave", line 3, in <module>
    from buildslave.scripts import runner
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\buildslave\scripts\runner.py", line 22, in <module>
    from twisted.python import reflect
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
_checkRequirements()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\__init__.py", line 37, in _checkRequirements
    raise ImportError(required + ": no module named zope.interface.")
ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zope.interface.
```

I've got it all installed here is my `pip freeze`:

```
Twisted==14.0.0
argparse==1.2.1
buildbot-slave==0.8.9
stevedore==0.15
virtualenv==1.9.1
virtualenv-clone==0.2.5
virtualenvwrapper==4.3.1
virtualenvwrapper-win==1.1.5
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens in a `python` prompt when you do `import zope.interface`? What about `import zope`?

Comment: In a python prompt, `import zope.interface` works, as does `import zope`

Comment: How are you running `C:\Python27\Scripts\buildslave` then?  Is it the same Python executable?

Comment: I was using a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall zope.interface and reinstall the version 3.6.0 using the command

```
pip uninstall zope.interface
pip install zope.interface==3.6.0
```

Hope this helps.